# Wordpress pre_get_posts and date_query showing blank screen

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to implement a filter on wp_query to show annual archives by School Year (sept - may) rather than jan-dec. When I view a yearly archive page, such as sitename.com/2017/, I get a white screen of death, and no PHP errors.

My code in functions.php looks like the following:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'school_year_filter' );

function school_year_filter($query) {
    if (! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_year() && $query->is_archive()) {

        $year     = get_query_var('year');
        $year2    = $year + 1;

        $query->set(
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'after'     => array(
                        'year'  => "$year",
                        'month' => '9',
                        'day'   => '1',
                    ),
                    'before'    => array(
                        'year'  => "$year2",
                        'month' => '5',
                        'day'   => '31',
                    ),
                    'inclusive' => true,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

I changed this line  `'date_query'=>array(` to `'date_query', array(`.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'school_year_filter' );

function school_year_filter($query) {
    if (! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_year() && $query->is_archive()) {

        $year     = get_query_var('year');
        $year2    = $year + 1;

        $query->set(
            'date_query', array(
                array(
                    'after'     => array(
                        'year'  => $year,
                        'month' => '9',
                        'day'   => '1',
                    ),
                    'before'    => array(
                        'year'  => $year2,
                        'month' => '5',
                        'day'   => '31',
                    ),
                    'inclusive' => true,
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Only_Display_Search_Results_After_Specific_Date

Comment: enable error reporting in wp-config file and check the error